# Bind to parent object in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, converters

I have a hierarcial class like this

```
Part
  SubPart
     SubSubPart1
     SubSubPart2
```

I have a control that is populated by SubSubPart and in that control i want to show information about the parent SubPart and Part. I want to use normal binding in xaml to display information about parent part.

Each part has a unique ObjectId as a property, each part has multiple properties that i want to display.

The control only knows about one subsubpart.

I realize that i can write a converter

```
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))

        { return "Design Part"; }
        else
        {

            IDataService applicationService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDataService>();
            IPartItem partItem = applicationService.GetEquipmentFromComponent(value.ToString());

            return partItem.PartData.Name;
        }
    }
```

and apply it like this

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
Text="{Binding Path=ObjectId,Converter={StaticResource partConverter}}" Margin="0,0,10,0">
</TextBlock>
```

But then i need to write a converter for every property of the parent parts. Any solutions out there.

Comment: Don't SubSubPart objects have a reference to the parent SubPart object? If they do, you could just use something like Path=MySubPart.ParentPart.Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the DataContext of your control using the converter and update your converter to just return the parent part

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ObjectId}" DataContext="{Binding Converter={StaticResource partConverter}}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
```

Comment: Excellent. This is the final version  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding Path=ObjectId, Converter={StaticResource partConverter},ConverterParameter=1}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="0,0,10,0"></TextBlock>

Answer (score 4):

You could do what you're looking for by using the `FindAncestor` mode of a `RelativeSource` binding.

For example the text property of a TextBlock would be the following:

```
Text="{Binding Path=ObjectId, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
    AncestorType={x:Type local:SubPart}, AncestorLevel=1}
```

where `local` would be declared to be the namespace where the class `SubPart` is declared.

You can follow the same pattern for the `Part` class, changing the `AncestorType` and `AncestorLevel` attributes as needed.

Comment: +1 although if `ObjectId` exists on SubPart's DataContext instead of being a Property on `SubPart`, then you'll need to bind to `DataContext.ObjectId`

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Sorry if my explanation was not good enough. The subparts are not controls its a data structure inside my viewmodel that the control is bound to and the control only knows about one single subsubpart.